# what is the correct SQL to get "most used query"

Tags: sql-server

i have a table called **Rides**

**id

car_id

distance**

i have another table **Cars**

**id

name**

i want to run a query that return the most drives per car (on cars that i have rid greater than once)

so the results i am looking for are something like this (to be returned in descending order):

Ford   10
BMW     8
Ferrari 5
Jeep    4

I have:

```
select car_id, COUNT(car_id) as Cid    
from Rides
group by car_id
order by cid desc
```

but i can't figure out how to eliminate items that are only 1 ride.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To filter derived columns, you can use a HAVING clause.

```
select car_id, COUNT(car_id) as Cid    
from Rides
group by car_id
having Cid > 1
order by cid desc
```

OR

```
having COUNT(car_id) > 1
```

If your particular brand of SQL doesn't like to use aliases in Having clauses.

Comment: i am getting an error on this "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'having'."

Comment: Sorry, had the order of clauses wrong. Having before Order By. (Edited Answer)

Comment: now getting another error: "Invalid column name 'Cid'", if i changed it to HAVING COUNT(car_id) > 1, it works

Comment: That query works for me. Sounds like your SQL flavour may be case sensitive or doesn't accept aliases in the having clause. I've added an alternate format in case it doesn't accept aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the HAVING clause--pun not intended

Answer (score 0):

homework?

try grouping by car_id...

Comment: HAVING does the comparison against the aggregate.

Comment: usually i try not to directly 'answer' homework - but instead offer guidance. thanks.